# background updates are not working properly

Tags: updates

Please, I need help to solve WordPress diagnostic issue:

> **Background updates are not working properly** Security Background updates ensure that WordPress can update itself if a security update is released for the version being used.
>
> - Error The `automatic_updater_disabled` filter is active.
> - Error All automatic updates are disabled.
> - Passed No version control system was detected.
> - Passed Your WordPress installation does not need FTP credentials to perform updates.
> - Passed All your WordPress files are writable.

Anyone can help me solve? :-) Please

Comment: Something you've got installed is turning them off. Can you search all of your files for automatic_updater_disabled? It's probably a plugin or theme. It might also be `define('AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true);` in wp-config.php.

Comment: /* Add any custom values between this line and the "stop editing" line. */


Hi,  Thanks.  my  wp-config.php  is like that:

define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', 'minor' );   
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */   and nothing changed